# SwiftUI Tap inside List doesn't trigger selection

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Newbie in SwiftUI. When I select an item in the `List` below, it only triggers `onTapGesture` if I press the `Text`. If I press outside the `Text` but in the "cell" it doesn't trigger. I would like it to be triggered, how ca I achieve this?

```
    List(viewModel.cities, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { city in
                VStack {
                    Text(city)
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity alignment: .leading)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .onTapGesture {
                    if isFocusedFromTextField {
                        from = city
                    } else {
                        to = city
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add background in the VStack using `.background()`. Because except the text rest of the view area is blank, and blank area not taking tap gesture.

```
       List(cities, id: \.self) { city in
            VStack {
                Text(city)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .background()    //just add this line
            .onTapGesture {
                print("tapped")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is fine to ignore taps on an already selected row, you can use `onChange(of: selection)`.

```
// modify the List with this, not the list rows
.onChange(of: selection) { city in
    if isFocusedFromTextField {
        from = city
    } else {
        to = city
    }
}
```

Otherwise, consider using a `Button` as the list rows instead. This still maintains the selectable nature of the list.

```
Button {
    if isFocusedFromTextField {
        from = city
    } else {
        to = city
    }
} label: {
    // replace this with a more complicated view if you want...
    Text(city)
}
// - style the button to look more like a Text if you want
// - get rid of the selection @State if you don't need it
// - if you do need the selection, you can style the buttons differently
// depending on selected state, using listRowBackground etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner version than an empty `.background()` is to directly modify the hit-testing area with [`.contentShape()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contentshape(_:eofill:)) (especially given that empty `.background()` modifier fills the background with "the default background", which isn't something exact):

```
[...]
VStack {
    Text(city)
}
.contentShape(Rectangle())
[...]
```

But do note that whichever version you choose, the very edges of your List item areas still won't be clickable/tappable. Those small leading and trailing edge areas seem to only be recognizing gestures when you use selection with your list or extend your views outside the regular list item area in some way.